Publishing events with priority attribute set
How does one go about setting the priority to a given message while publishing to Solace via REST API? Is it an HTTP header? Metadata attribute?

If you're talking about the SMF Message Priority it is not currently settable when posting messages into Solace using REST. All messages will get a default priority of 4.
